# c# rest webservice without IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest

Is there a good example/tutorial on how to create and run WCF REST webservice **without** IIS ?

I want to have a console application that'll run the webservice and not host it in IIS.

Comment: take a look [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/1407/)

Answer (score 5):

Just self host your service with System.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost in your console application. It will wire up the appropriate endpoint behavior / binding.

Comment: yeah i know that. i just wanted to see an example b/c i can't "see" the webservice from the browser after i do that.

Comment: @Rata  Why not?  A web browser is just as capable of displaying content from a self-hosted web service as from an IIS hosted web service.